# How to apply a theme to SQL Server Management Studio 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

Has anyone had any success with, for example, applying a 'dark' them to the Text Editor component of of SSMS 2008?

There was an old trick for 2005 which is no longer operational and has not been upgraded.  http://winterdom.com/2007/10/colorschemesinsql2005managementstudio

My eyes will thank you very much!  Cheers.

Comment: I'm not aware of any theme add-ins for SSMS 2008.

Comment: Did you read the comments thread there that gives the 2008 registry key?

Comment: Newer suggestions at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/112379/how-to-change-mssql-management-studio-theme

Answer (score 6):

I used this approach and theme provided here, it worked for me in SSMS 2008:

[Beautify Your Management Studio 2005/2008](http://www.jimmcleod.net/blog/index.php/2012/05/03/beautify-your-management-studio-20052008/)

> To install, simply backup your [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Shell\FontAndColors{A27B4E24-A735-4D1D-B8E7-9716E1E3D8E0}] registry key, and load in [this new set](http://www.jimmcleod.net/files/SSMS_2008_Jim_V1.reg.txt) (standard disclaimer about being careful with your registry, make sure you know what you’re doing, don’t blame me, etc). You can then either restart SSMS, or go to the Tools, Options, Environements, Fonts and Colors and simply click OK.

There is also a comment which provides the proper registry location for changing the theme in SSMS 2012, which only seems to differ by the version number.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this blog:

[Dark colour theme for SQL Server Management Studio](http://codeasp.net/blogs/raghav_khunger/microsoft-net/1646/dark-colour-theme-for-sql-server-management-studio)

Comment: Hi, sadly that hack is only applicable to 2005... I've not managed to tweak it for 2008/12 as of yet but I'll take another swing at it perhaps as it's certainly the closet solution.